# Tool for executing custom command in a network

Tags: windows, linux, networking, command-line, network-monitor

I need to perform some test on the devices present in a network via executing commands using REST API.

I have gone through some network monitoring tools but could not find one that can let me execute command on the device and return response of executed command.

So is there any open source tool that can let me execute custom commands (Not predefined) using REST API and give response in return?

Comment: It sounds like you want ssh access to each system (as that is the best way to execute arbitrary custom commands). Why does it need to be a REST API? Also what do you mean by "custom not predefined"? I would be tempted to downvote as not specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're not afraid to write an own shell script you could use `nmap` and then either `curl` or the `nmap scripting engine` to do what you want: scan the network using `nmap` and then either have `nmap` run a prepared script for each present node or have a shell script that runs a `curl` command for every present node.

Answer (score 1):

If the API already exists and you just want to test it and its responses, then nothing at all will ever beat [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

> Postman is used by 5 million developers and more than 100,000 companies to access 130 million APIs every month.

Visit the site for more, but it's he industry standard and I know of no better.